# How to append data to this object?

Tags: javascript

input:

```
[{ 
    email: 'sassa', 
    password: 'sas' 
}]
```

output:

```
[{ 
    email: 'sassa', 
    password: 'sas' ,
    valid: true
}]
```

i am having a response from node.js, and i want to add the 'valid' element in the object so i can use it later on. How can I achieve it? when I am using push, it is not working.

Comment: `object.valid = true;`

Comment: It is still not working

Comment: `var obj = { 
    email: 'sassa', 
    password: 'sas' 
}`

`obj.valid = true;`

Comment: @CharlesJames push is used to add data into array

Answer (score 1):

Just assign the new value like below.

```js
var obj = [{ 
    email: 'sassa', 
    password: 'sas' 
}];

obj[0].valid = true;

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your have two ways.

First
[image]

Second one.

[image]

In your case should be:

```
let a = [{ 
    email: 'sassa', 
    password: 'sas' 
}];

a[0].valid = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: Use Object Spread Operator (Most concise, modern, and recommended)

```js
const before = { 
    email: 'sassa', 
    password: 'sas' 
}

const after = {...before, valid: true}

console.log(after) // outputs {email: "sassa", password: "sas", valid: true}
```

Option 2: User Object.Assign (Works on more machines)

```js
const before = { 
    email: 'sassa', 
    password: 'sas' 
}

const after = Object.assign(before, {valid: true})

console.log(after)
```

Hope this helps,
Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Use Object assign to make:

```js
var obj = { 
    email: 'sassa', 
    password: 'sas' 
};
var result = Object.assign(obj,{valid:true});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is the ouput [ { userExist: true,
    _id: 5bade845a38f0315fc46e841,
    userFirstName: 'Charles Edwin',
    userLastName: 'Ison',
    userEmployeeId: '201403606',
    userMobile: '09168613103',
    userPassword: 'cH1590753',
    userTimeStamp: 2018-09-28T08:37:25.918Z,
    __v: 0 },
  valid: true ]

Comment: i want the valid: true is inside the curly braces

Comment: @CharlesJames if that's your output, your input is not how you describe it in your question. Your comment shows an array with an object in it .

Comment: Use: `Object.assign(obj[0], {valid:true});` if you want to set in the object array with index 0!

Answer (score 0):

As @AbdulBasit already mentioned, `push()` is only used to add data to arrays and not dictionaries.

You should set valid to `null` or `false` and then set it to `true`.

```js
var dictionary = {
  email: "myemail",
  password: "mypassword",
  valid: null
};
dictionary.valid = true;
if (dictionary.valid) {
  document.write("Valid is set to true.");
}
```